# JSC3D: translating object

Tags: javascript, jsc3d

I am trying to translate object in space, and I have this function which should translate object, its stored in .js file

```
 JSC3D.Matrix3x4.prototype.translate = function(tx, ty, tz) {
this.m03 += tx;
this.m13 += ty;
this.m23 += tz;
 };
```

but in another js file I am trying to implement real numbers and to move object, how can I call this function and change its parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

```
JSC3D.Matrix3x4.prototype.translate = function(tx, ty, tz) {

var t=0;
var g=0;
var h=0;

 t = parseFloat(document.getElementById('translate_x').value);
 g = parseFloat(document.getElementById('translate_y').value);
 h = parseFloat(document.getElementById('translate_z').value);
console.log(t);

    if(t!=0 || g!=0 || h!=0)
    {

        console.log(this.m03);
        this.m03 += tx;
        this.m13 += ty;
        this.m23 += tz;
        tx=t;
        ty=g;
        tz=h;
        this.m03 += tx;
       this.m13 += ty;
       this.m23 += tz;
   }
   else
   {
     this.m03 += tx;
     this.m13 += ty;
     this.m23 += tz;
   }
};
```

Comment: also this in another file


     viewer.onmousedown = function(x, y, button, depth, mesh) {
              if(button == 0/*left button down*/ && mesh != null) {
                // create a new material with a different color (blue for example)
                var newMat = new JSC3D.Material('', 0, 0x000080, 0, true);
                // set the new material to the selected mesh
                mesh.setMaterial(newMat);
                // tell viewer to render a new frame
                viewer.update();